# Woocommerce variable products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using woocommerce in my website. I need radio buttons instead of dropdown for variations on product page. For this, I have replaced the variable.php file with the following code :--

```
<?php
/**
 * Variable product add to cart
 *
 * @author  WooThemes
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 2.5.0
 *
 * Modified to use radio buttons instead of dropdowns
 * @author 8manos
 */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
 exit;
}
if ( ! function_exists( 'print_attribute_radio' ) ) {
 function print_attribute_radio( $checked_value, $value, $label, $name ) {
  global $product;
  // This handles < 2.4.0 bw compatibility where text attributes were not sanitized.
  $checked = sanitize_title( $checked_value ) === $checked_value ? checked( $checked_value, sanitize_title( $value ), false ) : checked( $checked_value, $value, false );
  $input_name = 'attribute_' . esc_attr( $name ) ;
  $esc_value = esc_attr( $value );
  $id = esc_attr( $name . '_v_' . $value . $product->get_id() ); //added product ID at the end of the name to target single products
  $filtered_label = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', $label );
  printf( '<div><input type="radio" name="%1$s" value="%2$s" id="%3$s" %4$s><label for="%3$s">%5$s</label></div>', $input_name, $esc_value, $id, $checked, $filtered_label );
 }
}
global $product;
$attribute_keys = array_keys( $attributes );
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form' ); ?>

<form class="variations_form cart" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data' data-product_id="<?php echo absint( $product->get_id() ); ?>" data-product_variations="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( wp_json_encode( $available_variations ) ) ?>">
 <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_variations_form' ); ?>

 <?php if ( empty( $available_variations ) && false !== $available_variations ) : ?>
  <p class="stock out-of-stock"><?php _e( 'This product is currently out of stock and unavailable.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>
 <?php else : ?>
  <table class="variations" cellspacing="0">
   <tbody>
    <?php foreach ( $attributes as $name => $options ) : ?>
     <tr>
      <td class="label"><label for="<?php echo sanitize_title( $name ); ?>"><?php echo wc_attribute_label( $name ); ?></label></td>
      <?php
      $sanitized_name = sanitize_title( $name );
      if ( isset( $_REQUEST[ 'attribute_' . $sanitized_name ] ) ) {
       $checked_value = $_REQUEST[ 'attribute_' . $sanitized_name ];
      } elseif ( isset( $selected_attributes[ $sanitized_name ] ) ) {
       $checked_value = $selected_attributes[ $sanitized_name ];
      } else {
       $checked_value = '';
      }
      ?>
      <td class="value">
       <?php
       if ( ! empty( $options ) ) {
        if ( taxonomy_exists( $name ) ) {
         // Get terms if this is a taxonomy - ordered. We need the names too.
         $terms = wc_get_product_terms( $product->get_id(), $name, array( 'fields' => 'all' ) );
         foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
          if ( ! in_array( $term->slug, $options ) ) {
           continue;
          }
          print_attribute_radio( $checked_value, $term->slug, $term->name, $sanitized_name );
         }
        } else {
         foreach ( $options as $option ) {
          print_attribute_radio( $checked_value, $option, $option, $sanitized_name );
         }
        }
       }
       echo end( $attribute_keys ) === $name ? apply_filters( 'woocommerce_reset_variations_link', '<a class="reset_variations cstm-reset" href="#">' . __( 'Clear', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>' ) : '';
       ?>
      </td>
     </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
   </tbody>
  </table>

  <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button' ); ?>

  <div class="single_variation_wrap">
   <?php
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_variation' );
    do_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation' );
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_variation' );
   ?>
  </div>

  <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button' ); ?>
 <?php endif; ?>

 <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_variations_form' ); ?>
</form>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form' ); ?>
```

It shows the radio buttons as I needed but the problem is that, the price is not displaying on variation products.You can check my website http://www.itsjal.com/store/product/led-lamp-par38/
Price should be displayed at the end when I select variations options. Can anybody help me to solve this problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this plugin. https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-radio-buttons/

This plugin also has its own template files if you want to customize it.